# Is there a C++ template way to loop on different enums?

Tags: c++, templates

In this topic I would like to know if a C++ way is possible to loop on different given enums ? The following source code is my proposition but doesn't compile.

```
enum class Fruit : int
{
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    APPLE   = 1
};
 
enum class Vegetable : int
{
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    CARROT  = 1
};
 
static const std::map<std::string, Fruit> FRUITS_MAP
{
    {"unknown", Fruit::UNKNOWN},
    {"apple",   Fruit::APPLE}
};
 
static const std::map<std::string, Vegetable> VEGETABLES_MAP
{
    {"unknown", Vegetable::UNKNOWN},
    {"carrot",  Vegetable::CARROT}
};

template<typename T>
T myFunction(const std::string &iName)
{
    T result{T(0)};
    if (std::is_same<T, Fruit>::value)
    {
        const auto &found = FRUITS_MAP.find(iName);
        if (FRUITS_MAP.end() != found)
        {
            result = found->second;
        }
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, Vegetable>::value)
    {
        const auto &found = VEGETABLES_MAP.find(iName);
        if (VEGETABLES_MAP.end() != found)
        {
            result = found->second;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I can't write methods with only changing return type because I get `error: ambiguating`

Comment: You can use `if constexpr`,  auto return type, and `return` in each branch what you need..

Comment: Please, may you write an exemple below ?

Comment: Where does the loop come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your code simply by adding `constexpr` in the lines:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T, Fruit>::value)
...
else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, Vegetable>::value)
```

And use it like:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(myFunction<Fruit>("apple")) << std::endl;
std::cout << static_cast<int>(myFunction<Vegetable>("carrot")) << std::endl;
```

If you sit on a decade outdated compiler ( why? ) you can simply use specialized templates:

```
template<typename T> T myFunction(const std::string &iName);

    template<>
Fruit myFunction<Fruit>(const std::string &iName)
{
    Fruit result{Fruit(0)};
    const auto &found = FRUITS_MAP.find(iName);
    if (FRUITS_MAP.end() != found)
    {
        result = found->second;
    }

    return result;
}

    template<>
Vegetable myFunction<Vegetable>(const std::string &iName)
{
    Vegetable result{Vegetable(0)};
    const auto &found = VEGETABLES_MAP.find(iName);
    if (VEGETABLES_MAP.end() != found)
    {
        result = found->second;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But here we can ask why we need templates as simply overloads with different names have the same effect. It depends on the real use case. If you have type lists you walk over with some MTP stuff, this may help, if it is handcrafted code which will call the given functions, the template stuff makes no sense.

Comment: My code is running under C++ 11 and your solution works only for C++ 17

Comment: Aha! Sorry, why you are using a decade old compiler? See my edit to use on a >10 years old compiler...

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate. Now it's working haha